# java parse date GRAVE null

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat, java.util.date

In this code,

```
        String str="Sun Feb 07 00:27:16 CET 2021";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    try {
        java.util.Date date=sdf.parse(str);
        System.out.print(date.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

It shows
GRAVE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Feb 07 00:27:16 CET 2021"
How to solve it plz!

Comment: Judging by your username I'd say your system's language may not be English, so you should pass a locale to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.

Comment: For those wondering: I think the OP’s system uses a French locale setting, and “GRAVE” translates to a “SEVERE” log level.

Comment: Yes, it utilizes french loc settings

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Not using the correct format: you have used `E` instead of `EEE`
2. Not using `Locale`: make it a habit to use the applicable `Locale` with date-time parsing/formatting API. Your date-time string is in `English` and therefore you should use an English-specific locale e.g. `Locale.ENGLISH`, `Locale.US` etc.

**Correct code:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str = "Sun Feb 07 00:27:16 CET 2021";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(str);
        System.out.print(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1612654036000
```

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str = "Sun Feb 07 00:27:16 CET 2021";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-07T00:27:16+01:00[Europe/Paris]
1612654036000
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.